# How to enable multiple displays under XFCE on cloud virtual machine?

Tags: ubuntu, xfce

I have setup an Azure Ubuntu VM. I installed the XFCE 4.12 desktop environment and use ThinLinc package to connect to the desktop. Now I want to enable multiple monitors under XFCE. How can this be done?

Currently when I go under the Display settings in XFCE only one display is shown:

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to change any settings. It should work automatically when you run the ThinLinc Client in fullscreen.